# Torelli theorem for veronese double cone(reference needed)

Tags: derived-categories, hodge-theory, fano-varieties

Let $Y$ be a smooth Veronese double cone, which is a smooth del Pezzo threefold of degree one, which can be regarded as a weighted hypersurface of degree 6 in $\mathbb{P}(1,1,1,2,3)$. I was wondering if Torelli theorem has been proved for this Fano threefold? What I am looking for is statement like $J(Y_1)\cong J(Y_2)\Longrightarrow Y_1\cong Y_2$, where $J(Y)$ is the intermediate Jacobian of $Y$. I found an article https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1070/IM1982v019n02ABEH001423
In this article, it introduces certain reconstruction of $Y_1$ via the image of Fano surface of lines under the Abel-Jacobi map. But I am not sure whether this can be regarded as a Torelli statement in terms of intermediate Jacobian.